# Facebook FanBox Widget demo

Tags: facebook, widget

is there a demo for the FanBox?

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fan_Box

I would like to include it in a design for a client which doesn't have a facebook fanpage yet.

Comment: I copy and pasted the iframe from another website ... works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the demo for that:

http://www.ohlalashopping.co.uk/

You can add fanbox to your site easily through this amazing widget by the facebook:

http://www.facebook.com/facebook-widgets/fanbox.php

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe width="265px" scrolling="no" height="500px" frameborder="0" src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/fan.php?id=19292868552&amp;connections=16" class="fan_box"></iframe>
```

used the exemple from the officeal Facebook Blog

http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=262